# ¿Cómo inserto en sql un arreglo independiente para dos columnas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que se llama `TB_ProductCities` en la cual tengo que insertar dos campos, los cuales son `idProduct` y `idCity`, desde el frontend me envían dos variables cada una es un arreglo que contiene  múltiples valores pero la misma cantidad, los campos que voy a recibir prácticamente son estos:

esta seria la variable para idProduct : `@idProducts varchar(500) = '4,7,9,12,78,11',`

esta seria la variable para idCity : `@idCitys varchar(500) = '1,3,4,66,62,101',`

dejo una url de la imagen "https://ibb.co/fFjMM1k" ,como esta en esta imagen debería quedar

este es el código de como lo estoy intentando hacer pero me dice que la sintaxis es incorrecta. ¿alguien sabe como lo podría hacer ?

```
declare @idCitys varchar(500) = '4,7,9,12,78,11'
declare @idProducts varchar(500) = '1,3,4,66,62,101'



declare @ProgramacionIngresos2 table(IDError int)

    insert into [TB_ProductCities]
      ([idProduct]
      ,[idCity])
 

    select [value] as idProduct,
    from string_split(@idProducts,',')
    [value] as idCity
    from string_split(@idCitys,',')
```

Comment: En cual de todas las bases de datos que pusiste estas tratando de hacer esto? es importante que pongas las etiquetas correctas

Comment: @gbianchi en SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que los dos arreglos son independientes, sugiero que proceses primero cada arreglo a una estructura más amigable que luego puedas utilizar para construir la información que quieres insertar.

Puedes hacerlo a variables tipo tabla. Como necesitamos relacionar cada *registro* en cada arreglo por su posición, yo me valdré de un campo entero declarado como *identity* para tener de manera automática un consecutivo que *numera* cada elemento encontrado en la cadena. Llenamos cada tabla por separado valiéndonos de la función `string_split()`.

Finalmente, puedo hacer *join* de estas dos variables tipo tabla para obtener los registros con un elemento de cada arreglo, que es lo que insertaré a la tabla final, relacionandolos por su posición en el arreglo. Como bono adicional, si los dos arreglos no son del mismo tamaño esto automáticamente se va a ajustar a los pares que pueda armar:

```
declare @idCitys varchar(500) = '4,7,9,12,78,11'
declare @idProducts varchar(500) = '1,3,4,66,62,101'

declare @Cities table(numero int not null identity(1, 1), idCity int);
declare @Products table(numero int not null identity(1, 1), idProduct int);

insert into @Cities (idCity) select value from string_split(@idCitys, ',');
insert into @Products (idProduct) select value from string_split(@idProducts, ',');

insert into TB_ProductCities (idProduct, idCity)
select c.idCity, p.idProduct
  from @Cities c
       inner join @Products p on p.numero = c.numero
```